# Power BI Matrix with rows based on slicer selections AND aggregates

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

I have a table that contains interviews held in all offices in my country which contains the following columns:

```
State
Office Name
Wait Time
Interview Length
```

I have a handful of slicers that allow you to select a state, a slicer to select one office, and a slicer to select a second office. Neither office selected has to explicitly belong to the selected state and they don't have to belong to the same state.

I need a matrix that will display as follows:

|  | Avg Wait Time | Avg interview length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Whole Country | value | value |
| Selected State | value | value |
| Selected Office 1 | value | value |
| Selected Office 2 | value | value |

The idea being to be able to compare the average of the entire country to the average for the selected state and compare these to two selected offices. The second selected office is optional. If a 2nd office isn't selected, it should be blank.

My measures:

```
AvgWaititme = AVERAGE([Wait Time])
AvgIntLength = AVERAGE([Interview Length])
```

Is this even possible? The best I can do right now is have individual cards showing the values but this takes so much more space than a table would.

[One drive link to pbix](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ffpxswr52m7vls1mxgfek/Testing.pbix?rlkey=mbct2att4d4rj2kpk7zqx4892&dl=0)

Comment: Do you have a sample .pbix?

Comment: Sure thing! https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ffpxswr52m7vls1mxgfek/Testing.pbix?rlkey=mbct2att4d4rj2kpk7zqx4892&dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you how to do one and you can use the same logic for the second column.

Create 4 disconnected tables as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Make sure they have no relationships to anything.

Add 3 slicers to your page and use the values for State Selector, Office Selector 1 and Office Selector 2 in each (3 of your new tables).

[image]

Create a matrix and drag the Rows Table to the rows like this.

[image]

Create a measure:

```
Avg Wait Time = 
VAR x = SELECTEDVALUE('Rows'[Value])
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    x = "Whole Country", [AvgWaitTimeSoFar](REMOVEFILTERS()),
    x = "Selected State",[AvgWaitTimeSoFar](REMOVEFILTERS(), TREATAS(VALUES('State Selector'[State]), Interviews[State])), 
    x = "Selected Office 1",[AvgWaitTimeSoFar](REMOVEFILTERS(), TREATAS(VALUES('Office Selector 1'[Office]), Interviews[Office])), 
    x = "Selected Office 2",[AvgWaitTimeSoFar](REMOVEFILTERS(), TREATAS(VALUES('Office Selector 2'[Office]), Interviews[Office])), 
    BLANK()
)
```

Add it to the values. That's it.

[image]